# Hide/Show Divs with Javascript and sort by value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, sorting

I have these two scripts, one sorts divs by a value in a div class (price) and the other shows or hides divs based on class name with buttons. (box a, box b etc, inside a "parent" class.)

The problem is they do not work together, you can show a class but not sort the results by price, the price sorting only works on all the divs at once, and breaks after, you need to reload.

fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/qjwL1pqa/4

Is there any way to have a single script that does both? lets you show hide divs based on a class, and sort the results by price (ascending / descending) and vice verse?

I hope this makes sense.

Script for showing / hiding Divs based on class name:

```
var $boxs = $("#parent > .box");
var $btns = $(".btn").on("click", function() {

var active = 
$btns.removeClass("active")
  .filter(this)
  .addClass("active")
  .data("filter");

$boxs
.hide()
.filter( "." + active )
.fadeIn(450);

});
```

Script for sorting Divs based on class value:

```
$('#byPrice').on('click', function () {
 $('#parent div.price').map(function () {
  return {val: parseFloat($(this).text(), 10), el: this.parentNode};
 }).sort(function (a, b) {
  return a.val - b.val;
 }).map(function () {
  return this.el;
 }).appendTo('#parent');
});
$('#byPrice1').on('click', function () {
 $('#parent div.price').map(function () {
   return {val: parseFloat($(this).text(), 10), el: this.parentNode};
 }).sort(function (a, b) {
   return b.val - a.val;
 }).map(function () {
   return this.el;
 }).appendTo('#parent');
});
```

Example Product Div:

```
 <div id="parent">

    <div class="box a">
        <div class="product_box">   
            <div class="price">19.99</div>
            </div>
    </div>

 <div/>
```

Comment: Can its possible for you to create a working code snippet or fiddle of this code. It will be highly easy if we have any of these.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/qjwL1pqa/4

Answer (score 0):

I have modified your fiddle code a bit. Please check it and let me know if that is what you are looking for:

http://jsfiddle.net/qjwL1pqa/6/

Did following modifications:

1) removed the `btn` class from sorting buttons:

```
<button class="" id="byPrice">BY PRICE ￪</button>
<button class="" id="byPrice1">BY PRICE ￬</button>
```

2) For sorting we just need to consider all prices which are visible, so modified code as follows:

```
$('#parent div.price:visible').map(function () {
```

3) referring top most div node with class `box` while iterating:

```
el: this.parentNode.parentNode
```

Hope it will help you.

Comment: Thank you! That's perfect. Im still learning but I understand my error thanks again.